# Distortions in a Subway Map

Tags: differential-geometry, image-processing, map-projections

The NYC subway map - like most subway maps - isn't shown to scale. Is there a way to visually represent the distortion of the map in terms of area? More specifically, suppose you have the set of coordinates representing stations on the distorted map, $(x_1,y_1), ..., (x_n,y_n)$. Suppose you also have the set of coordinates for the original map, $(u_1,v_1), ..., (u_n, v_n)$.

Is there a good way to plot the distorted map and overlay a color-coded image which represents the localized area compression at each point? My only lead so far is to use something akin to Tissot's indicatrix to denote local compression. But this approach has some technical issues given a finite set of points. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I appreciate the suggestions so far but I really would like to create a completely colored map with the following simple properties: Darker colors indicate compressed distances and lighted colors indicate stretched distances. A really simple example is shown in the plot below. The points originally lie in a square but get transformed into a rhombus.[image]

Comment: The simplest approach would be to simply draw each subway line in alternating colors according to real-world distance, like [a scale on a map](http://wall-maps.com/chart-carte/mileScale.jpg). Thus lines that are drawn shorter will have more closely spaced alternations, giving a visual impression of being compressed. At stations you could then connect equal real-world distances on incident lines with elliptical arcs, producing a generalization of Tissot's indicatrix.

Comment: It seems to me a big part of the difficulty is to infer a continuous mapping of the plane from the given dataset, which includes only a finite number of points. How you use that mapping to color the display is secondary to finding the mapping in the first place.

Comment: I totally agree. My original thought process was to find the transformation matrices for the given points and then use some interpolation method to get all other points in the plane. But there's no obvious way to do that. I had hoped that perhaps this type of problem had a viable solution already.

Answer (score 1):

Take an image of an evenly spaced grid, and distort it such that each initial point moves to the corresponding final point. Then place the resulting image over the map and the density and shape of the lines will visualize the distortion.